# MIQP to MILP linearization in Java Eclipse using Cplex concert

Tags: java, optimization, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I am coding in Eclipse using Cplex concert technology to solve a Mixed Integer programming problem. The objective function is a QP (product of binaries). I wanted to linearize the MIQP to MILP. I introduced cuts (constraints) and coded them all in Java eclipse. The model is running and terminating with a wrong answer. Earlier, the MIQP model was run without any linearized objective function term but with linearized constraints. Both MIQP and MIQP with linearized constraints gave the same optimal solution. But with the new setup, it is not terminating with the same solution. I want some help in the Cplex code and Java code to solve this problem. I will share the code upon request.

Additional information based on inputs are as follows
When I say the wrong answer, what I try to explain is as follows. I have a MIQP problem with QP objective function and linear constraints. When I solve this in Cplex with all default settings in the solver parameter settings, I got an optimal solution in say 900 seconds and objective function solution as say 200. Now I want to improve the formulation and hence introduced some linearized constraints (Added as cuts and kept the QP obj. function as it is and solved again. This time I got the same optimal solution 200 with a run time just 13s. Now I want to introduce the (product of binaries = quadratic term in the objective as a simple binary variable) and solved the problem. The algorithm terminated in just 10s with obj. function value -649199 something. My linearization is correct. I checked the math. The below code will share the details about Java code.

**Objective function**
IloNumExpr fullexpr = cplex.numExpr();

```
        for(int t=1; t<timeLimit; t++) {
            for(int l=0; l<limitD[t]; l++) {
                for (int q=0;q<limitD[t];q++) {

                // creating expressions and adding to objective function
                double p1l = (delta/2)*(d1LT[t].density((l+.5)*delta)+d1LT[t].density((l+1.5)*delta));                      
                double lDp1l = (l+1)*p1l*delta;
                IloNumExpr expr1 = cplex.prod(h1, cplex.sum(-lDp1l, cplex.prod(p1l, S1[t])));

                double pplushprime = p+h1prime; 
                IloNumExpr expr3 = cplex.prod(pplushprime, cplex.sum(cplex.prod(lDp1l,cplex.sum(1, cplex.prod(-1, y[l][t]))),cplex.prod(p1l,cplex.prod(-1, S1[t]))));
                IloNumExpr expr4 = cplex.prod(pplushprime, cplex.prod(delta*p1l, E[l][q][t]));
                fullexpr = cplex.sum(fullexpr, expr1, expr3, expr4);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Linearized constraints**

```
      for(int t=0; t<timeLimit;t++ {
          for(int l=0; l<limitD[t]; l++) {
              for(int q=0; q<limitD[t]; q++) {
                  cplex.addLe(cplex.sum(y[l][t],y1[q][t]),cplex.sum(cplex.prod(2, E[l][q][t]),1) ,"new1");
                  cplex.addGe(cplex.sum(y[l][t],cplex.prod(-1, y1[q][t])),cplex.sum(cplex.prod(1, E[l][q][t]),-1),"new2");                      
                  cplex.addGe(cplex.sum(y1[q][t],cplex.prod(-1, y[l][t])),cplex.sum(cplex.prod(1, E[l][q][t]),-1),"new3");
                  cplex.addGe(cplex.sum(y[l][t],y1[q][t]),cplex.prod(1, E[l][q][t]),"new4");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please attach the relevant source code to your question and also take a look here in your spare time: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Cplex will typically linearize this automatically.

Comment: You asked the exact same question here: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/527282/miqp-to-milp-linearization-model-using-ilog-cplex.html
The question is missing a lot of details that we need to help you: What is the wrong answer? Is the solution infeasible? Is it sub- or super-optimal? Is the objective function value different or only the x vector? Are you sure your linearization is correct? Can you edit your question to show the linearization? And/or add the original and linearized model?

Comment: Hi Erwin, Cplex will automatically linearize and solve it. But the run time is higher than the linearized constraints. These constraints are added as cuts. With the QP objective and linearized constraints, the run time is just 13s. Whereas without the cuts, the run time is around 900s for a medium size problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Daniel. Sorry I did not share the details here. I will answer all your questions now.

Comment: In order to debug that I suggest to assign names to all variables and constraints and then export to an LP file. Then look at this LP file and make sure the linearization shows up as exected. If that is done, then take a look at the solution vectors of the super-optimal solution. There will be some values that are incorrect. Look at the constraints that are supposed to exclude these incorrect values. There may be a problem with these constraints.

Answer (score 1):

A general answer cannot be given since not all information to reproduce the problem is available. So I turn one of my comments into an answer to illustrate how you can debug this yourself:

In order to debug that I suggest to assign names to all variables and constraints and then export to an LP file. Then look at this LP file and make sure the linearization shows up as expected. If that is done, then take a look at the solution vectors of the super-optimal solution. There will be some values that are incorrect. Look at the constraints that are supposed to exclude these incorrect values. There may be a problem with these constraints.